# Adding type constraints to the context of instance declarations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, instance, typeclass

I am trying to represent weighted edges. I eventually want to have OutE to be an instance of Eq and Ord, with the constraint that etype is an instance of Eq and Ord. Assume I have following file as temp.hs:

```
data (Ord etype)=> OutE vtype etype = OutE {destVertex:: vtype, edgeValue::etype}

applyFunBy accessor ordfun = (\x y -> (ordfun (accessor x) (accessor y)))

instance Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
    --(==) :: Ord etype => (OutE vtype etype) -> (OutE vtype etype) -> Bool
    --(/=) :: Ord etype => (OutE vtype etype) -> (OutE vtype etype) -> Bool
    (==) = applyFunBy edgeValue (==)
    (/=) = applyFunBy edgeValue (/=)
```

when I load this in ghci, I get the following errors:

```
temp.hs:10:19:
    Could not deduce (Ord etype)
      from the context (Eq (OutE vtype etype))
      arising from a use of `edgeValue' at temp.hs:10:19-27
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord etype) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the first argument of `applyFunBy', namely `edgeValue'
    In the expression: applyFunBy edgeValue (==)
    In the definition of `==': == = applyFunBy edgeValue (==)

temp.hs:11:19:
    Could not deduce (Ord etype)
      from the context (Eq (OutE vtype etype))
      arising from a use of `edgeValue' at temp.hs:11:19-27
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord etype) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the first argument of `applyFunBy', namely `edgeValue'
    In the expression: applyFunBy edgeValue (/=)
    In the definition of `/=': /= = applyFunBy edgeValue (/=)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

If include the lines for the type signatures for (==) and (\=), I get:

```
temp.hs:6:1:
    Misplaced type signature:
    == ::
      (Ord etype) => (OutE vtype etype) -> (OutE vtype etype) -> Bool

temp.hs:7:1:
    Misplaced type signature:
    /= ::
      (Ord etype) => (OutE vtype etype) -> (OutE vtype etype) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You limited `etype` to be `Ord` in the defintion of `OutE`:

```
data (Ord etype) => OutE vtype etype = ...
```

But in the `Eq` instance, you're actually trying to define the instance for *any* `etype` unrestrictedly.

```
instance Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
```

Of course this doesn't work since `OutE` itself is just defined for `Ord etype`s, thus you'll have to add the typeclass constraint to the instance definition as well.

```
instance (Ord etype) => Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
```

Note that one definition of either `==` or `/=` is sufficient for the typeclass to work.

---

Note that it's often easier and therefore considered better style not to have typeclass constraints on `data`-types, but just on instances/methods that actually require the functionality of the typeclass.

In many cases, one does not need the constraint and just ends up with unnecessarily clumsy type signatures.

Take e.g. some ordered map type `Ord key => Map key value`.

What if we just want to list all keys? Or get the number of elements? We don't need the keys to be `Ord` for these, so why not just leave the map unrestricted with simple

```
getKeys :: Map key value -> [key]
getLength :: Map key value -> Int
```

and just add the typeclass when we really need it in a function like

```
insert :: Ord key => key -> value -> Map key value
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data (Ord etype)=> OutE vtype etype = OutE {destVertex:: vtype, edgeValue::etype}
```

First issue:  This is consdered bad style.  Your data type declarations shouldn't have constraints.  Leave the constraints to the functions, much like the containers package does.

```
instance Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
```

Second "issue".  You can just add `deriving (Eq)` after your data declaration.  I'm guessing you know that and are writing the instance explicitly for your own learning (good for you)...

```
instance Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
    (==) = applyFunBy edgeValue (==)
    (/=) = applyFunBy edgeValue (/=)
```

Third issue: you can't compare values for equity if they are of the `Eq` class.  So you want to say `etype` is constrained by Eq:

```
instance (Eq etype) => Eq (OutE vtype etype) where
    (==) = applyFunBy edgeValue (==)
    (/=) = applyFunBy edgeValue (/=)
```

Fourth, you don't actually need to write an instance for both (==) and (/=).  The defaults will work once you define one of these.

Comment: `deriving (Eq)` will generate equality operators based on **all** record fields (and thus generate a cumbersome `Eq` instance with a `Eq vtype`) whereas the explicit instance given in the question just compares based on `edgeValue`.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice he was doing that till after writing that bit.  Thanks for pointing that out.